# Silverlight Assembly.CodeBase problem

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, silverlight-2.0

"This member has a SecurityCriticalAttribute attribute, which restricts it to internal use by the .NET Framework for Silverlight class library."

Is there a way to access this information? (The original location of the Silverlight assembly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can never access any information that has SecurityCriticalAttribute, that can only be accessed via Silverlight itself internally. But why do you want to access Assembly.CodeBase? Most of what you need to run, silverlight gives you access via browser interface. Think of silverlight as only alternative to JavaScript, where you really can not access client's machine information or any other system information. All you can do is talk to the server you came from.